# RTKGPS+ or RTKLIB configuration of rover and input streams for Stonex S8plus

Tags: gps, assisted-gps, rtklib

I've tried to use RTKGPS+ and RTKLIB with external antenna and via NTRIP to communicate with Continuously Operating Reference Station (CORS) of my country (MAKPOS), but I couldn't make connection (i have user, password, port 9001, NTRIP mountpoint: iMAX-Auto, host: makpos.katastar.gov.mk) I have Stonex S8plus and i like to try to use smartphone+external antena via NTRIP to connect with MAKPOS and do Network RTK or DGPS.

Simply the configuration of this system is by these segments:

Referent base stations (14 stations in radius of 50-70km between each of them). Leica GRX 1200+ & Leica AR 25 … 9 stations Leica GRX 1200 GG Pro & Leica AT 504 GG … 2 stations Leica GX 1230 GG & Leica AX 1202 GG … 3 stations Control Center: Leica GNSS Spider (controlling and managing with network, RT Proxi Server and NTRIP Caster) Leica GNSS Spider QC (controling the quality of data and coordinates on network points) Leica GNSS Spider WEB (distribution of RINEX) Services in MAKPOS DGPS (accuracy 0.3-0.5 m), it uses RTCM 2.x and the transfer is by GPRS and NTRIP RTK (accuracy 0.02-0.04m), it uses RTCM 2.x and RTCM 3.x and the transfer is by GPRS and NTRIP Precise positioning with additional processing, (<0.01 m), RINEX, transfer via Internet, mail..

Does anyone have done RTK or DGPS with this app or with another app? Where can I find configuration file for Stonex S8plus?

I made configuration to sent NMEA via bluetooth in Stonex Assistant, at 1hz page 52 in user manual.

Link of RTKGPS+ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpsplus.rtkgps&hl=en

Stonex S8plus user manual: http://www.stonexpositioning.com/jdownloads/Public/Manuals%20and%20tutorials/English/GNSS%20receivers/S8%20PLUS/s8_plus_user_manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am not fully understanding the question, you should be able to make your NTRIP/DIP settings in the Assistant software. Once configured, the receiver would output the corrected NMEA data from the receiver. The need for the RTKGPS+ and RTKLIB wouldn't be needed as long as the NTRIP settings can be completed within the Assistance software, which it appears it can be.

Are you looking to send the corrected NMEA data to another device? Or do you have a data collector with field collection software? A lot of the field data collection software has the ability to also configure the GNSS receiver's settings as well.

Comment: With Stonex receiver I got software named Stonex Asistant, in software i set parameters like parameters in user manual page 52: http://www.stonexpositioning.com/jdownloads/Public/Manuals%20and%20tutorials/English/GNSS%20receivers/S8%20PLUS/s8_plus_user_manual.pdf  I want receiver to sent NMEA to smartphone, than smartphone sent via NTRIP to CORS network and receive corrected RTCM so if it is possible to process RTCM and got final coordinates.

Comment: Per page 46 you can enter the NTRIP details for the GNSS network. It appears your network provides RTK corrections, so you would enter the IP address, port number as well as your username and password into the Assistant software. Then you would configure your rover to send the NMEA data you mentioned to the 3rd party device. If you are having issues try contacting your dealer and they may have an application note to help with the detailed settings needed.

Comment: I've done that with another 3rd party app, and it's OK, but my target was RTK LIB and RTKGPS+. With this setup Receiver receive data from satellites, than it sent to MAKPOS, system sent corrections to receiver, than receiver process RTCM and sent via Bluetooth corrected NMEA. I like to make test like this (Receiver receive data-sent NMEA via Bluetooth or USB to smartphone-Smartphone via NTRIP communicate with MAKPOS-MAKPOS sent corrections to smartphone-Smartphone process RTCM and show corrected position (FIX/DGPS)). RTK LIB is software in theory capable for this process.

Comment: I guess I am not seeing the benefit in doing this type of process? If your receiver is capable of receiving the DGPS or RTK corrections via the NTRIP server and providing the desired results (final coordinates as you stated) in real-time, what purpose does the RTKGPS+ or RTK LIB app provide the the process?

Comment: No,no, thats not the point of this project, I use this receiver only for measurements for duct infrastructure in telecommunication, but I need something with accuracy <1 meter for Aerial infrastructure but cheaper solution. It will be used for acquisition of GIS data for Aerial infrastructure or for some other GIS measurements. Now I used this receiver only to be sure that it will work with RTK LIB and for my Master thesis, in future we will buy another cheaper modules.

Comment: There are a number of GNSS receivers out there that would be able to achieve that accuracy via SBAS (WAAS, EGNOS, etc.) and you wouldn't have to have any connection to NTRIP server. For example, the Leica Zeno 20 would be capable of this via SBAS (even in an L1 only configuration). According to the data sheet it would be capable of 40cm or better when utilizing the DGNSS corrections.

Comment: That's right via SBAS, WAAS, EGNOS some receiver could achieve accuracy <1m, but receivers like Leica Zeno 20 are over 5000$, I need 2 receivers every day, so I need over 10 000 $ to buy professional receivers like Zeno. Ublox Neo M8P or some similar modules are under 500$ for 2modules, service for MAKPOS is 400euro per year for DGPS correction with accuracy of 40-60cm, if I made some app for collecting data combined with RTKLIB I could work with lower costs. But now it's not priority work, I made this for my Master Thesis.

Comment: Good luck on your thesis.